# How to pass JSON information from Flask to Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

This is my first attempt at interfacing a Flask backend with an Angular frontend. I am trying to get the frontend to collect JSON data generated on the backend. This is what the code looks like.

Flask:

```
@app.route('/weather/loc', methods=["POST","GET"])
def say_hi():
    location = request.form.get("location", default="London")
    try:
        location, condition, temp = weatherAtLocation( location)
        content = "Hello there %s, your weather is %s with a temperature of %s°C." %(location, condition.lower(), temp)
        return_dic = {
        "location":location,
        "condition":condition.lower(),
        "temperature": temp
        }
        return jsonify(return_dic)
    except:
        return jsonify( {})
```

This seems to work fine after manual testing. My problem is in the Angular, the function making the call is:

```
hasclicked(){
  this.HttpClient.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/weather/loc",
  {
    "location":"London"
  })

}
```

My problem is that I am unfamiliar with TypeScript and could not find an example showing me how to store the returned JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `post()` method or else the call will never be executed. You will then be able to interact with the response. See [here for more information regarding making POST requests](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request).